# infinite series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{ij}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can we prove:

$\frac{1}{1-x^j}= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{ij}$

Can anyone give me some ideas to prove that?

Comment: @Maio9el What is $x$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Comment: $x$ is a real, whereas $j$ is a natural.

Comment: $x^{ij}= (x^{j})^{i}$ now use geometric series for $x^{j}$ instead of $x$.

Comment: @Mai09el The equality isn't true for every $x\in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you know that $$\frac{1}{1-r}=\sum_{i\geqslant 0}r^i\;\;\text{ for }|r|<1$$ Now let $r=x^j$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^{ij}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(x^{j})^i=\frac{1}{1-x^j}$$ if $|x^j|<1$